# Full disk encrypted while installing Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, encryption

I am a new Ubuntu user, although I've used Ubuntu 14 before.

Today when I was installing 16.04 LTS, it gave me the option for disk encryption, and in a hurry, I ticked it, then entered the password too.

After that, I didn't install Ubuntu as a partition problem came up. I came back to the Ubuntu try screen. It tells me that the disk is encrypted but it is not accessible from file manager in Ubuntu even after entering password.

On the *installing Ubuntu* screen, it is showing up as encrypted in partition screen so I could not install it as it wants to format the full hard disk.

Now I don't know how to decrypt it. How can I decrypt my hard disk?

Answer (score 2):

Since the installation failed and presumably you just need to reinstall, you don't even need to unlock the encrypted partition created by the installer, you can just remove it and then start over:

Select "Try Ubuntu" instead of "Install Ubuntu" when it boots from USB.  This will load a live version of Ubuntu.   From there, you can open "Disks" to [manage the partitions](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/disk-partitions.html) on your disks.  Be aware that deleting or formatting partitions will make the data stored there inaccessible and Disks will show all discovered media, so be careful not to delete the wrong thing.

You can delete partitions individually, but if you want to use Ubuntu for the entire disk, the easiest option would be to format the whole disk which will remove all partitions (use the three vertical bars at the top right of the application).  It will ask if you want to use MBR or GPT.  Unless you have old hardware you should select GPT as the partition scheme.

Then you can launch the installer which will be a link on the desktop of the live USB, or you can reboot and select the "Install Ubuntu" option, whichever you prefer.

---

If for some reason you needed to actually decrypt that disk, you would be also be able to perform this task through the included Disks application by selecting the encrypted partition, hitting the play button to mount it, at which point it would ask for the password.

If you didn't remember what password you used, however, you would be out of luck.